# Using multiple ssh key pairs in CuteFTP

Tags: sftp

I understand the philosophy of using one private/public key pair for all your interactions. However, most FTP clients allow the loading of keys on a per-connection basis.

I'm merging two systems with different private keys but CuteFTP appears to only allow one globally accepted key pair. Unfortunately, I'm required to use CuteFTP. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of manually updating the key path in the configuration window or creating a script to change the contents of the key file, the answer is no. Fortunately, EFT Server (also a GlobalScape product) will support multiple public keys for one account. This allowed me to migrate from one key to another without a service interruption.